# Angular ng-controller conflicting with ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use a custom control to get contenteditable elements in Angular as described in [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example). However, I also need to use a controller which causes the contenteditable portion of the code to fail even if my controller is completely empty.

[This Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1tbJ5qeIpACJwhfYTKP?p=preview) shows the desired behavior, but does not include the controller.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div>
    <h1 contenteditable ng-model="test">123</h1>
    <textarea ng-model="test"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
```

[This Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1tbJ5qeIpACJwhfYTKP?p=preview) shows the addition of the controller to the div on line 10 of the HTML file, however the desired behavior from the first Plunker is no longer there.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <h1 contenteditable ng-model="test">123</h1>
    <textarea ng-model="test"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly register a controller with the app - global controller functions are not allowed by default:

```
.controller("mainController", function mainController($scope){

});
```

This is now the default option in Angular v1.3+

(of course, you have other issues with binding to untrusted HTML, but that's a different story)